# Why I can´t use a variable bringing data for an IN condition?

Tags: sql, database, parameters

```
DECLARE @variableNVARCHAR(100)

SELECT @variable=param_desc
FROM PARAMETERS 
WHERE param_cve='DPTS'  --(This variable brings the '1','2','3')



SELECT * FROM EMPLoyees WHERE department IN ('1','2','3') --This works.

SELECT * FROM EMPLoyees WHERE department IN (@variable) --This doesn't work.
```

I think is because is comparing for example 1 as string = to this '1,'2','3' as string, What Can I do?

Comment: Which RDBMS are you using?

Comment: The `IN` clause expects a **list of something** - list of int or whatever. What you're supplying in your second example is just a **single string** - which *might* contain a representation of a list of things - but it's **not** a list of things in itself. If you read a string like this from a database table, you need to **parse and split** that string into a list of items that works for `IN` ...

Answer (score 0):

Suppose that the 1st `select` statement returns only one row (in any other case your method is considered as... problematic).

Also, suppose that `@variable = ' '1','2','3' '`.

In such case your last query actually is:

```
SELECT * FROM EMPLoyees WHERE department IN (''1','2','3'')
```

Then, while there is a no any department named '1','2','3' the empty set is a very correct answer ;)